# How to configure message format to syslog in WildFly

Tags: jboss, wildfly, syslog

When using JBoss 5.1 with this appender:

```
<appender name="SYSLOG" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender">
   <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
   <param name="Facility" value="LOCAL7"/>
   <param name="FacilityPrinting" value="true"/>
   <param name="SyslogHost" value="localhost"/>
   <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ABSOLUTE},%c{1}] %m%n"/>
   </layout>
</appender>
```

I see next message for log record (in EventLog Analyzer):

```
local7:[13:32:45,763,SendingPool] Sending pool task executed. Pool size is [0
```

In WildFly 8.2.1 I have next configuration for handler:

```
    <syslog-handler name="SYSLOG">
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
        <server-address value="localhost"/>
        <facility value="local-use-7"/>
    </syslog-handler>
```

Message:

```
1 2016-07-08T13:30:34.943+03:00 - java 910 com.mycompany.component.p - ﻿Sending pool task executed. Pool size is [0
```

How I can change message format for syslog?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there isn't a way using the `syslog-handler` to format the message. This was an oversight when it was created and there is a long standing [JIRA](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-109) to fix this.

However you can use a `custom-handler` and use a formatter.

```
/subsystem=logging/pattern-formatter=syslog-formatter:add(pattern="local7: [%d{hh:mm:ss,SSS},%c{1}] %s")
/subsystem=logging/custom-handler=syslog:add(class=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.SyslogHandler, module=org.jboss.logmanager, named-formatter=syslog-formatter, properties={hostname="localhost", facility="LOCAL_USE_7", protocol="TCP", useCountingFraming=true})
/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:add-handler(name=syslog)
```

Note if you want the `local7:` to be printed that needs to be part of the format. There is not way to prepend the facility name to the message.

Looking at:

```
1 2016-07-08T13:30:34.943+03:00 - java 910 com.mycompany.component.p - ﻿Sending pool task executed. Pool size is [0
```

That looks like the raw message minus the priority. By default the syslog handler will use the RFC 5424 format. If you want to use RFC 3164 add `syslogType=RFC3163` to the `properties` attribute in the above custom-handler add operation and remove the `useCountingFraming=true`. Note the `useCountingFraming=true` may need to removed anyway. It depends on your syslog server setup.

Comment: With this settings WildFly hangs on start for several minutes and not logging to server, I tried with and withour useCountingFraming.

Comment: Is your syslog server setup to use UDP or TCP? I thought log4j defaulted to TCP so I assumed that's what should be used, but I could be wrong.

Comment: TCP, server on default 514 port

Comment: Weird. I used the above configuration with no problems. If it's just a slow TCP connection you could wrap it in an async-handler.

Comment: I have a very basic question. Did you build a custom-handler section to hold the lines /subsystem... ? Where do you put the 3 lines of your example? If you did build a custom-handler, is there any trick to it? I've looked for examples but nothing seems related to the above.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question. The 3 CLI commands should create create a formatter, create a custom handler, then assign the custom handler to the root logger.

Comment: ok that's the missing piece. You are showing a command line interface set of commands. These then update the standalone.xml on the fly for persistence?

Comment: Yes. It's always best to use a management interface (e.g. CLI, web console) to update the configuration. In this case it has the benefit of not require the server to be shutdown or even restarted.